# Installing support files for app using sql 2005 where server is on another computer

Tags: sql-server, installation, inno-setup, software-distribution

I have a managed C++ application that connects to SQL Server 2005 Express databases on the same computer and over a network. My problem is that if the database is located on another computer over the network, the client machine will not have the needed DLLs files installed from SQL Server.

I can't force my users to install SQL Server 2005 Express on the client machine just to get the needed support files. So my question is, is it safe to installed the dependent files to the GAC on the user's computer? Or, does MS have a command line install package for just this purpose?

The files from SQL Server that my application show as being dependent on are as follows:

Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
Microsoft.SqlServer.RegSvrEnum
Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication
Microsoft.SqlServer.Rmo
Microsoft.SqlServer.ServiceBrokerEnum
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum
Microsoft.SqlServer.WmiEnum

If it helps, I'm using the Inno-Setup program for my installer. This has to be a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to install the full version of SQL Server, but you do need the necessary drivers.  Installing the SQL 2008 SMO package on the client should resolve these issues.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6C3E9EF-BA29-4A43-8D69-A2BED18FE73C&displaylang=en

Comment: I saw those packages, which I will try. The problem is they don't list the contents, so with the list of dependancies of my app I'm just not sure the XMO package has them all. I'll try and post here again.